# Is it legal to translate my own Master's thesis? I wrote my thesis in my native language and now I am applying for PhD programs in English

Tags: phd, masters, translations

I already finished my Master's degree a while back. Now I am applying for Ph.D. programs and a lot of them require some academic publication, and since I only have a Master's thesis I don't know If I should translate it.

Comment: Are you asking if it is legal or if it is a good idea to do it from the perspective of PhD admissions?

Comment: It's quite possible that professors on admissions committees are willing to read publications in your native language.

Comment: Note that a privately made translation does not count as official translation for legal documents. It probably won't matter to the committee for a scientific dissertation.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't given up copyright to it, then you are within your rights to provide a translation. Just mark it as such, citing the original. There are no problems with this.

If you have given up copyright (say, to a publisher) then they hold the rights, but will probably give you permission (a license) to do this. But it doesn't count as a second publication - just as a translation - since the content is the same. In some cases, your agreement with a publisher may already include this right.

It might make your work more accessible to an application committee, of course.

Comment: I wonder if there is at all a legal problem for a translation for restricted academic purposes only (such as an admission).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, actually anyone can translate anything as long as they don't "publish" it. But the meaning of "publish" is open to interpretation.